# Laravel | Forbidden access when calling a json file in public folder in javascript

Tags: javascript, json, laravel

I am a beginner in laravel. I am trying to access a file  in path /js/ph-json/regions.json and the message in the console says 403 forbbiden. How do I allow this?

```
 const url = '{{asset("ph-json/region.json")}}';
    // Populate dropdown with list of regions
    $.getJSON(url, function(data) {
        $.each(data, function(key, entry) {
            dropdown.append($('<option></option>').attr('value', entry.region_code).text(entry.region_name));
        })
    });
```

This should get the json but I don't know but it is blocked access.